# Port 445 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4! in xampp and Apache is not working

Tags: php, apache

```
Initializing Control Panel
5:52:00 PM  [main]  Windows Version: Windows 7 Professional SP1 32-bit
5:52:00 PM  [main]  XAMPP Version: 5.6.31
5:52:00 PM  [main]  Control Panel Version: 3.2.2  [ Compiled: Nov 12th 2015 ]
5:52:00 PM  [main]  Running with Administrator rights - good!
5:52:00 PM  [main]  XAMPP Installation Directory: "c:\xampp\"
5:52:00 PM  [main]  Checking for prerequisites
5:52:50 PM  [main]  All prerequisites found
5:52:50 PM  [main]  Initializing Modules
5:52:50 PM  [Apache]    Problem detected!
5:52:50 PM  [Apache]    Port 445 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4!
5:52:50 PM  [Apache]    Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
5:52:50 PM  [Apache]    You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
5:52:50 PM  [Apache]    or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
5:52:50 PM  [main]  Starting Check-Timer
5:52:50 PM  [main]  Control Panel Ready
5:53:03 PM  [Apache]    Problem detected!
5:53:03 PM  [Apache]    Port 445 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4!
5:53:03 PM  [Apache]    Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
5:53:03 PM  [Apache]    You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
5:53:03 PM  [Apache]    or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
```

I m getting as Port 445 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4! in xampp and Apache is not working
what is the error it is showing ?

Comment: Is it Linux OS?

Comment: (You sure you mean 445 to begin with? HTTPS default port would be 443 ...)

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay        No It window

Comment: yes it is 445 .......actually yesterday i have directly close the pc  and today when i restart my pc the window told me to check the disk utilities and i check the disk upto 100%.....i think this may cause this problem

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that port 445 is already in use. Try to use 443, if it is SSL you want. You should find your http.conf in C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra

Comment: I don't have 445 port

Comment: i think some service is got active in services

Comment: it is window event Collector